# FOREIGN KEY doesn't apply after saved in MYSQL 8 in digitalocean Managed Databases

Tags: mysql, digital-ocean, mysql-8.0

i created digitalocean Managed Databases for the development. the MYSQL version was 8.0.20
The problem is after saved the SQL script there is no error. table is created successfully.
But when i go to the table after that the table has no applied FOREIGN KEY to the table.
I'll put my code below before and after the incident.

**This is the query before insert.**

```sql
CREATE TABLE `user_reg`  (
  `user_reg_id` int(0) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_reg_id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `user_id`(`user_id`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `user_reg_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `sp_user` (`user_bid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;
```

**This is the query after got a dump from mysql.**

```sql
CREATE TABLE `user_reg`  (
  `user_reg_id` int(0) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_reg_id`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `user_id`(`user_id`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `"user_reg_ibfk_1"` FOREIGN KEY () REFERENCES `"sp_user"` () ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci ROW_FORMAT = Dynamic;
```

The MYSQL server has not absorbed the foreign keys.

```sql
FOREIGN KEY () REFERENCES `"sp_user"` () ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE
```

Comment: How did you get that dump? I'd suspect about the dump tool first.

Comment: there's no issue with the dump. the thing is the mysql server doesn't accept  FOREIGN KEY inside of the table. After  insert table query three is no relation between tables.

Comment: i tried it in my local mysql server. then it works well.

Comment: Asking a question suggests you don't know the answer. Perhaps you shouldn't pre-emptively reject potential solutions. MySQL engines either support or do not support foreign keys—there's no intermediate status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change and try Global SQL mode ANSI_QUOTES

ANSI_QUOTES
Changes " to be treated as `, the identifier quote character. This may break old MariaDB applications which assume that " is used as a string quote character.